# LaTeX the table out of page

Tags: tables

I want to create table like this .
[image]

I don't know how to create header of table like that.
This is Latex script.

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|} \hline
Product ID&A&Specify Size&Error(\%)&A&Specify Size&Error(\%)&A&Specify Size&Error(\%)\\ \hline
1&Method new&6&11.70&Method+Data&No&3.24&Method+Data&6&10.55\\ \hline
2&A& 1\\ \hline
3&B& 1\\ \hline
4&A& 1\\ \hline
5&B& 1\\ \hline
6&A& 1\\ \hline
7&B& 1\\ \hline
8&A& 1\\ \hline
9&B& 1\\ \hline
10&A& 1\\ \hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

When I run script the table width out of page like this. How to set long word to next line and merge some column.
[image]

Comment: Could you please turn your code fragment inot a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the relevant packages and the documentclass you use? Regarding linebreaks in table cells, you might be interested in the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different suggestion using `makecell` in combination with a smaller fontsize. I have also added the first row of the table using `\multicolumn` and vertically centered the first cell using `\multirow`. The following example contains a second table without vertical lines. There I have used the horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package and slightly decreased the `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\small
\centering
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|} \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell[cc]{Product \\ ID}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3}\\ \cline{2-10}
 & A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)} & A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}& A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}\\ \hline
1 & \makecell[cc]{Method \\new} & 6&11.70 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & No & 3.24 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & 6 & 10.55\\ \hline
2&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
3&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
4&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
5&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
6&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
7&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
8&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
9&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
10&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}



\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccl} \toprule
\multirow{3.25}{*}{\makecell[cc]{Product \\ ID}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
& A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)} & A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}& A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}\\ \midrule
1 & \makecell[cc]{Method \\new} & 6&11.70 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & No & 3.24 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & 6 & 10.55\\ 
2&A& 1\\ 
3&B& 1\\ 
4&A& 1\\ 
5&B& 1\\ 
6&A& 1\\ 
7&B& 1\\ 
8&A& 1\\ 
9&B& 1\\ 
10&A& 1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can make such a table fit the page, not only using linebreaks with `makecell`, buut also reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default) and loading `geometry` to have more decent margins (if you don't use marginal notes). I added a demonstration of the use of `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}l|} \hline
\thead{Product\\ ID} & \thead{A} & \thead{Specify\\ Size} & \thead{Error \\ (\%)} & \thead{A } & \thead{Specify \\ Size} & \thead{Error\\(\%)}& \thead{A} & \thead{Specify\\ Size} & \thead{Error\\ (\%)} \\ \hline
1 & \makecell{Method\\\ new} & 6 &11.70 & \makecell{Method\\+Data} & No & 3.24 & \makecell{Method\\ +Data}& 6 & 10.55 \\ \hline
2&A& 1 & & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\ \hline
3&B& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
4&A& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
5&B& 1 & & & & & & & \\ \hline
6&A& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
7&B& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
8&A& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
9&B& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
10&A& 1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]